# Airflow Worker giving error (Celery command failed on host) after successfully completing task in GCP Cloud Composer

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

My task completes successfully in the airflow worker. But when I check the logs I always see this error after successful completion. The actual task/dag does not fails, but still It gives following error.

```
airflow-worker Task exited with return code 0

airflow-worker [efdf6e5b-39c6-4526-9b7c-2521acc64fcb] Failed to execute task <object object at 0x7f9111d076c0> is not a valid _MethodDefault.

airflow-worker Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 130, in _execute_in_fork args.func(args) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 103, in wrapper return f(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 387, in task_run _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 189, in _run_task_by_selected_method _run_task_by_local_task_job(args, ti) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 247, in _run_task_by_local_task_job run_job.run() File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 247, in run self._execute() File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/local_task_job.py", line 132, in _execute self.handle_task_exit(return_code) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/local_task_job.py", line 164, in handle_task_exit self.task_instance.schedule_downstream_tasks() File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2606, in schedule_downstream_tasks partial_dag = task.dag.partial_subset( File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2188, in partial_subset dag.task_dict = { File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2189, in <dictcomp> t.task_id: _deepcopy_task(t) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2186, in _deepcopy_task return copy.deepcopy(t, memo) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 153, in deepcopy y = copier(memo) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1175, in __deepcopy__ setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo)) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 264, in _reconstruct y = func(*args) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 339, in __call__ return cls.__new__(cls, value) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 663, in __new__ raise ve_excValueError: <object object at 0x7f9111d076c0> is not a valid _MethodDefault

airflow-worker Task airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command[efdf6e5b-39c6-4526-9b7c-2521acc64fcb] raised unexpected: AirflowException('Celery command failed on host: airflow-worker-thlz2 with celery_task_id efdf6e5b-39c6-4526-9b7c-2521acc64fcb')

airflow-worker Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 734, in __protected_call__ return self.run(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 96, in execute_command _execute_in_fork(command_to_exec, celery_task_id) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 111, in _execute_in_fork raise AirflowException(msg)airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Celery command failed on host: airflow-worker-thlz2 with celery_task_id efdf6e5b-39c6-4526-9b7c-2521acc64fcb
```

I am using following version of composer (2.1.7) and airflow (2.4.3)
in GCP (composer-2.1.7-airflow-2.4.3)

Comment: I've recently observed the same issue in many of our DAGs. Not sure if this is related composer health check